# How can we display a Side - Navigation Bar menu using Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to display a Side-Navigation Bar using a JSON response(which can be dynamic) as shown below:

```
    [{
     "A": "A-Value",
     "B": [{
          "C": [{
               "D": [{
                    "E": "E-Value",
                    "F": "F-Value",
                    "G": "G-Value",
                    "H": "H-Value"
               }],
              "I": "I-Value",
              "J": "J-Value",
              "K": "K-Value",
              "L": "L-Value"
        }, {
           "D": [{
                "E": "E1-Value",
                "F": "F1-Value",
                "G": "G1-Value",
                "H": "H1-Value"
        }],
        "I": "I1-Value",
        "J": "J1-Value",
        "K": "K1-Value",
        "L": "L1-Value"
    }],
    "L": "L2-Value"
}, {
    "L": "L3-Value"
}, {
    "L": "L4-Value"
}, {
    "L": "L5-Value"
}, {
    "c": [{
        "D": [{
            "E": "E2-Value",
            "F": "F2-Value",
            "G": "G2-Value",
            "H": "H2-Value"
        }],
        "I": "I7-Value",
        "J": "J7-Value",
        "K": "K7-Value",
        "L": "L7-Value"
    }],
    "L": "L6-Value"
   }]
}]
```

and the above response should be displayed in the pic as shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNS41.png)

I tried using ng-material-multilevel-menu but it didn't worked because its JSON structure format is fixed ?

Comment: You could use Angular material tree https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview to achieve this